# Problems mixing jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I was working on this page:
http://bigbassbrian.com/beta/photo.php

I add the 2 following jQuery plugins:

1. http://youhack.me/2011/07/15/google-plus-photo-stack-animation-using-jquery-and-css3/
2. ColorBox, A jQuery Lightbox

Now when I click on the album "With artists", the modal window opens with no problem, but the albums still on top and might be on the back of the modal window.

¿How to send to back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS problem. You have to change your CSS; http://bigbassbrian.com/beta/css/style-photo.css at line 20 there is a `z-index` definiton which has same value of lightbox wrapper, change it smaller then `9999`. Like:

```
.image_stack img { /* css style for photo stack */
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 9998; // !!! Change this value, make it smaller then 9999 !!!
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    /* WebKit */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    /* Opera */
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    /* Standard */
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```